# Copy struct with a embed pointer

Tags: go

```
type A struct{
v int
}

type B struct{
*A
}

b:=B{new(A)}
c:=b
b.v=2
println(c.v)//2 not 0
```

My problem is illustrated in the above code. I don't quite understand what is happening here, I assume it's that the v belongs to .A which is a pointer, so copying doesn't copy the value, but I'm not sure. Also, is there a way to solve this problem? I can't change the embed to value because i need the methods on pointer receivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you included, `A` is a struct with a member variable `v` whose type is `int`, and `B` is a struct with member variable `A` whose type is `*A`. Thus, when you assign `c:=b`, `c` becomes an instance of struct `B`, and `c.A` is a copy of `b.A`, which is a pointer, so they both point to the same location.

You said you need methods on pointer receivers. That doesn't mean you need `*A`, it only means you need `A` to be addressable, so when you call the methods its address can be taken. That is:

```
type B struct {
  A
}
```

where

```
func (a *A) f() {...}
```

you can still do:

```
b:=B{}
b.f()
```

because at this context, the address of `b` can be taken.

Comment: I need pointer receiver because some methods of A may change v.

Comment: You don't need a pointer struct member to use a pointer receiver. In the example I gave, `b.f()` has a pointer receiver, without declaring `b.A` as a pointer. What matters is that when you call a method, the receiver is addressable.

Comment: "I need pointer receiver because some methods of A may change v." yes, the answer acknowledges that.  You ned a pointer receiver, but A does not have to be a pointer.